# why does bootstrap-datepicker empty the value of a select element using select2?

Tags: jquery-select2, bootstrap-datepicker

I've got a modal that I'm working on, attempting to use select2 with an asny call to the server to load data and boostrap-datepicker.

Notice in the below screenshot, if the multi-select has been selected and the select the datepicker, the multi-select emptys itself of information.

[image: https://cl.ly/image/3727221E2X46/Screen%20Recording%202015-04-07%20at%2005.02%20PM.gif]

There are neither obvious configuration details for either library or javascript errors in the console.

I'm unclear what might be happening here, thoughts?

Comment: Next time I would recommend including enough code to reproduce this issue, as a picture isn't that helpful for future visitors who might have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had an error in the boostrap modal event listener, I was using

`$(@modalClass).on 'show.bs.modal', (event) =>`

when I should have been using

`$(@modalClass).on 'shown.bs.modal', (event) =>`

notice `shown` and the modal event was firing every time the modal was interacted with in any way.